# Jackson with JSON: private attributes instead of public

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON:

```
{
   "name": "TEST",
   "data": [["Toto", true, 42], ["ABC", "DEF", false]]
}
```

"data" value is a list of list of JSON elements (either string, integer, or boolean).

I made it work using a simple POJO with public attributes:

```
public class MyDecoder {
  public String name;
  public List<List<Object>> data;
}
```

But now, I would like my attributes to be private, so I'm using a constructor:

```
public class MyDecoder {
  private String name;
  private List<List<Object>> data;

  public MyDecoder() {
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public MyDecoder(
      @JsonProperty("name") String name,
      @JsonProperty("data") List<List<Object>> data)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

But this is failing with:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "data" (Class XXX.MyDecoder), not marked as
>   ignorable

What did I miss?
I guess it's related to `List<List<Object>> data`, because Jackson had no problem  with `String name`.
But then, I don't understand why it worked in the version with public attributes.

I'm using jackson 2.7.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe. getters and setters. .

Answer (score 1):

Try adding getters and setters:

```
public class MyDecoder {
    public String name;
    public List<List<Object>> data;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<List<Object>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<List<Object>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And test it:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyDecoder myDecoder = objectMapper.readValue("{\n" +
                "   \"name\": \"TEST\",\n" +
                "   \"data\": [[\"Toto\", true, 42], [\"ABC\", \"DEF\", false]]\n" +
                "}", MyDecoder.class);

        System.out.println(myDecoder.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
Surprisingly, adding "void setData(List<List<Object>> data)" and removing the constructor did the job, even without setName()!
If someone can explain why...

Comment: However, I still would like to make it work with a constructor.
Adding get/set is like making the attribute public...

Answer (score 0):

As to warnings, if there is a JSON property that does not have any way to be set (via visible setter or field, or @JsonCreator annotated constructor with @JsonProperty annotated parameters), an exception will be thrown -- unless configuration has been changed to ignore such "unknown" properties.

Did you try this way

```
public class MyDecoder {

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("data")
  private List<List<Object>> data;

  public MyDecoder() {
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public MyDecoder(
       String name,
       List<List<Object>> data)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can be a problem with Object :D